# What is wrong with my JS setTimeout() parameter

Tags: javascript, settimeout

In the following snippet, I can't see why the commented-out line doesn't work, while the line after does work:

```
function clicked()  {
    var t1 = setInterval(print, 100);
//  setTimeout(clearInterval(t1), 16000);
    setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(t1)}, 1600);
```

Answer (score 4):

The first argument of `setTimeout` should be a function.

`clearInterval` is a function.

`clearInterval(t1)` is the *return value* you get when you **immediately** call the function.

Comment: Good, thanks.  I haven't used SO for a bit, can I mark the question as answered?

Comment: @JohnWhite — http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

that is because setTimeout's first parameter is a supposed to be a function.
that's why you can give it things like "print" which i assume is a function in your context, or "function(){clearInterval(t1)}" which is an anonymous function that uses clearInterval.

however, the value of "clearInterval(t1)" which is  calling clearInterval on t1, is the return value of clearInterval, which probably isn't a function. that is all.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be:

```
setTimeout(clearInterval.bind(null,t1), 1600);
```